# TYPO3 how use 'use'

Tags: php, typo3

I know, that are some stupid questions, but I am a little bit confused.
[image]

Above, it is a screenshoot from `https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/7-Controllers/1-Creating-Controllers-and-Actions.html`.

As you can see, in one case there is no '\' before `MyVendor`, in another one it is. Are both way possible?

In my extensions I have under `Classes` the following structure.

[image]

If I use the `use` function, It is not necessary to `Classes in the statement.

`use MyVendor\ExtName\Controller\MainController` is enough?

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: Look at this comment in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php#112937

Answer (score 2):

1. You are `use`'ing namespace, not file structure, so you must `use` exact namespace
2. If you want to use methods from class, you must `use` that class. If function (not method) is under namespace, then that function must be used (as there is no class to use)
3. Leading `\` is optional, but preferred style is without leading `\`

---

```php
// a.php
namespace MyVendor\ExtName\Controller;

function test() {
    echo 'Test2';
}

class MainController {
    public static function test() {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}

// b.php

namespace AnotherVendor\ExtName\Controller;

class MainController {
    public static function test() {
        echo 'Test 3';
    }
}

// c.php

namespace MyVendor\ExtName\Utilities;

use MyVendor\ExtName\Controller\MainController;
use AnotherVendor\ExtName\Controller\MainController as AnotherController;
use function MyVendor\ExtName\Controller\test;

class MainUtility {
    public function foo() {
        MainController::test();
        AnotherController::test();

        test();
    }
}
```